# Does rooting stop OTA updates for nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, ota-update, 5.0-lollipop

I have nexus 5 with 4.4.4 and rooted it with towelroot.
will i be able receive a lollipop OTA update or should i flash a factory image manually.
my build number is KTU84Q.
Will i get lollipop 5.0 for my rooted nexus 5.
i didn't use any custom recovery ..please answer my question.